# Support Iscroll on select menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscrollview

The thing is, I have a Jquery Mobile + Iscrollview (iScroll wrapper for JQM) app,

And one or more SelectMenu (data-native=false) with a dynamic filter (The code is based on the example of JQM documentation), and I want to allow to scroll the filtered results.

The "solution" I reach at this point (the one in "page two" on example), made an screen height popup, where it would be much better a 5 elements popup size, and it doesn't apply the scroll to the dialog view, that is displayed instead of the popup when the options in the select are bigger than a certain quantity.

```
$(listview).wrap('<div id="' + id + '-iscrollWrapper"></div>');
$("#" + id + '-iscrollWrapper').attr("data-iscroll");
$("#" + id + '-iscrollWrapper').iscrollview();
$("#" + id + '-iscrollWrapper').iscrollview("refresh");
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xperiments_matias/3ZQXL/1/)
(if is not working, it maybe because of filehosting of js specifics files)